# How does Google Talk work?

Tags: google-talk

How does [Google Talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Talk) work? When I am connected to my friend for a talk, what acts as an **intermediate** one to transfer my voice? Is that a Google server behind it (which act as an intermediate? Or does it provide a point-to-point protocol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They use XMPP ( jabber )

[Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)

Answer (score 5):

Try to look at these articles:

- [GoogleTalk Architecture](http://highscalability.com/googletalk-architecture)
- [Architecture lessons from Google Talk](http://surana.wordpress.com/2007/12/25/architecture-lessons-from-google-talk/)